# Difficulty to recognize pattern reading

Tags: c#, file

I have a `.txt` file that's something like this:

```
5260|productCode1|data01|data02|data03|data04
5270|data05|data06|productCode1|data07
5270|data08|data09|productCode2|data10
5260|productCode2|data11|data12|data13|data14
5270|data15|data16|productCode1|data17
5270|data18|data19|productCode2|data20
```

How do I find all the lines that start with 5270 and have the product code I want(lets say productCode2, returning only the fourth line) ?

Edit: 5260 and 5270 are just line starters, they're not ids. The .txt file i'm working with has nothing like a key value

Comment: Can you share what have you tried so far?

Comment: Where are you stuck? Go line by line, filter for "startswith" 5270, split by "|", productcode is index 3, filter for productCode you want ...

Comment: @Pedro For clarification: You want to filter (1.) for lines starting with "5270" _and_ (2.) then out of the remaining you want only those where the "productCode" column matches a certain value, am I right? And you want the full line of the match, also correct?

Comment: Question edited, hope i'm a little more clear now (btw, you got it, that's exactly what i need)

Comment: One more: Can "data" fields by any chance be equal to a productcode? For example `"5270|productCode2|someDataValue|myActualProductCode|someOtherData"`?

Comment: Yes, its possible, albeit extremely unlikely - someDataValue may start like myActualProductCode, or be equal.

Comment: Can we safely assume the productCode of lines that start with "5270" is always in the 4th Column? So, always like this: `<LineStart = 5270>|<Data>|<Data>|<PRODUCTCODE>|<Data>` ?

Comment: Yes, the lines follow this template

Answer (score 2):

This returns all lines, which have the required condition:

```
string productcode = "productCode1";
string id = "5270";

var result = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\file.txt")
                   .Select(x => x.Split('|'))
                   .Where(x => x.First() == id && x.Any(y => y == productcode));
```

I assume that the productCode can be in any position

Comment: Mind that datafields must never be equal to productcodes for this to work properly.

Comment: without knowing more about the data structure I can't improve my answer

Comment: I am fully aware of that. Just wanted to give a "heads-up".

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can try the following,

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace ReadAllLines
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var path = @"C:\Users\username\Documents\MyFile.txt";

            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path, Encoding.UTF8);
            string yourProductCode;

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                if (line .Contains("5270|"))
                {
                  string[] myLine= line .Split('|');
                  if (myLine[3] == yourProductCode)
                  {
                   // myLine[] has all your data with the product code you want
                  }

                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Fildor you are right I edited the code, now the array has all your data with your unique productcode

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication147
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test1.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<string, List<List<string>>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<List<string>>>();

            string line = "";
            while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                line = line.Trim();
                if (line.Length > 0)
                {
                    string[] splitData = line.Split(new char[] { '|' }).ToArray();
                    if (dict.ContainsKey(splitData[0]))
                    {
                        dict[splitData[0]].Add(splitData.Skip(1).ToList());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dict.Add(splitData[0], new List<List<string>>() {splitData.Skip(1).ToList()});
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (List<String> code in dict["5270"])
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Product Code : {0}; Code : '{1}'; Data : '{2}'","5270", code[2], string.Join(",", code));
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

"*How do I find 5270 that have the product code I want?*"

Will return all lines with the met criterias.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

public string[] ReadFile(string fileName)
{
    return File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
}

public string[] QueryFile(string fileName, string productCode, string lineStarter)
{
    var data = ReadFile(fileName);
    return data.Where(x => x.StartsWith(lineStarter) && x.Contains(productCode)).ToArray();
}
```

From this point, you can split the data as per intended usecase.

Usage:

```
QueryFile("Path_To_My_File.txt", "productCode2", "5270");
```

Output:

```
5270|data08|data09|productCode2|data10
5270|data18|data19|productCode2|data20
```

Oneliner:

```
public string[] QueryFile(string fileName, string productCode, string lineStarter)
{
    return File.ReadAllLines(fileName).Where(x => x.StartsWith(lineStarter) && x.Contains(productCode)).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Attention, "5270" is a filter criterion, not the productcode.

Comment: Fildor is right, and plus you are missing one condition.

Comment: You missed a point. "5270" is not the desired output. OP knows, result must be "5270" because that is what he wants to filter for. _Additionally_ he wants to filter for the product code. In other words: Result should be a collection of all lines that start with "5270" _and_ have the desired productcode.

Comment: From what I can read, thats not apparent in his question. Or rather, that's not how I'm interpreting it. I think he means, he has a productCode, how does he find the "id" of that productCode?

Comment: Well, question states _"How do I find 5270 that have the product code I want?"_ , example data contains lines with 5260 and 5270, not unique, all lines contain one field marked as "productCodeN" (with N in [1,2]). So what would be the point in finding "5270"? It's not unique. So, I conclude we need the whole line.

Comment: See comments to question and Pedro's edit.

Comment: I upvoted to make up for the downvote, because I think it isn't fair, anymore. _But_ I still think this could be improved. As is, lineStarter and productCode can occur anywhere in the line. But we know, the lineStarter must be the first thing in the line ...

Comment: @Fildor Fixed your point (and thank you)!

Comment: `527` will return items with produce code `5270` aswell

Comment: But then again, stringmatching is just stringmatching. If you look for 527 in a string, 5270 is a match.